# Apache should not match domains without subdomain

Tags: apache, vhosts

I'm not a particularly good admin but a programmer. Nevertheless I need to configure this apache webserver right now.

I have a domain `abc.sub.domain.com` and a VHOST which matches this domain. But the VHOST also matches `sub.domain.com` which should just lead to Apaches default page and not inside my application directory.

Here is my conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.sub.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

Include /path/to/local/config/httpd-vufind.conf
```

The (open source) application build its whole config on environment variables that's why I need to include this conf file. This file seems to be included always, regardless of the domain.

Now, I want to disable this include while the domain does **not** completely match.

Then, I'd like to set up a default VHOST which only matches `sub.domain.com`. On this domain phpMyadmin and similar tools should work.

Here is how my default VHOST looks like. Under `sites-anebled it's called`000-default` and is on the first position.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@email.com
    ServerName sub.domain.com   
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But this does not help to solve my problem. `sub.domain.com` is still routed into the fist VHOST config (with include statement). How can I do the include **only** if the domain matches?

Answer (score 0):

By default apache matches the very first VirtualHost for any unmatched `ServerName`. Add another VirtualHost section **above** yours one, and it will catch any unmatched host. Other VirtualHosts with specified names add further.

Comment: How do I add them above? I use a2ensite to enable the vhosts. And I already tried to use the default vhost which was added as 000-default as first entry in the list. That did not help.

Comment: I've added my default VHOST config, which does not solve the problem.

Comment: Try to understand the order of loading virtual hosts and config files. First, apache loads main `httpd.conf`. If there are some vhosts defined, first of them becomes default and matches any request for non-exisent domains. Then apache repeats this iteration for each included files in order they follow in `httpd.conf`, and so on.

Comment: There is no `httpd.conf` on my Debian system. When I uncomment the `include` everything works (except the targeted software). The `include` seems to be executed nevertheless its ServerName does not match. Probably because it's not inside the `<VirtualHost>` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Including the VHOST config in `apache2.conf` (before the vhosts dir is included) helped